# SQL Server 2012 - Disable Job On Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, jobs

I have a job on server B, which is linked to server A. Is it possible to disable a job that exists on server B in the context of server A? I have tried the following command from server A and receive an error message.

```
EXEC SERVER_B.msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_name = N'test_job', @enabled = 0
```

Error message:

```
Msg 14262, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_verify_job_identifiers, Line 67
The specified @job_name ('test_job') does not exist.
```

I also tried creating a stored procedure on server B that executes the above command. The procedure works when executing it from the context of server B, but not from server A. Is it possible to disable a job on a linked server?

Comment: The simple answer is that yes it is possible to run sp_update_job via linked server (just did a quick verification of my own).    The error message is pointing out a different stored procedure (sp_verify_job_identifiers) which would lead me to believe you have certain permissions but not others and that it is those other permissions that are keeping you from completing this successfully.  Take a look here (https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/110894/msdb-permission-sqloperatorrole.html) hopefully it will help you with getting those permissions if that is indeed your issue.

Comment: Did you try: `MENU` > `QUERY` > `SQLCMD` ( activate it )....`:connect Your_server_name EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_name = N'test_job', @enabled = 0`

Comment: @mskinner Thanks - that link gave me the answer. I just needed to add the linked server user to the SQLAgentOperatorRole.

Answer (score 3):

I added the linked server user to the SQL Agent Operator role and the issue has been resolved.

```
EXECUTE sys.sp_addrolemember @rolename = 'SQLAgentOperatorRole', 
                             @membername = 'linked_server_user'
```